# Immutable object

Tags: java

Добрый день. На одном из собеседований столкнулся с темой immutable объектов. Попросили написать для примера класс Person с полями Date birthDate и String name и сделать его immutable конечно. Вот, что я отдал:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Person {

    Person (Date birthDate, String name) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate; 
        this.name = name;
    }

    private Date birthDate;
    private String name;

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

На что интервьюер ответил, что остается возможность изменить этот объект n-м количеством способов.
После его исправлений код выглядел так:

```
import java.util.Date;

final class Person {

    Person (Date birthDate, String name) {
        this.birthDate = new Date(birthDate.getTime()); 
        this.name = name;
    }

    private Date birthDate;
    private String name;

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, каким образом можно изменить объект описанный до исправления и осталась ли возможность изменить код после исправления, не используя при этом рефлексию?

Comment: Такое было решение. На счет создания нового объекта Date в конструкторе - согласен, т.к. он изменяемый. Но на данном этапе также интересует возможность изменения объекта Person, если не делать данную предосторожность.

Answer (score 6):

Всё просто: `Date` - клас мутабельный, в первом варианте можно получить объект `Date` из вашего класса `Person` и изменить его как-нибудь так:

```
Date birthDate = new Date();
Person p = new Person(birthDate, "vega");   
// сейчас birth date - текушая дата
birthDate.setTime(0);
// а теперь - 1 января 1970 года
```

В исправленном варианте в конструкторе вместо переданного значения `Date` полю присваивается его копия, поэтому описанный выше метод не сработает. Зато стработает такой способ:

```
Person p = new Person(new Date(), "vega");   
// сейчас birth date - текушая дата
Date d = p.getBirthDate();
d.setTime(0);
// а теперь - 1 января 1970 года
```

От этого можно защититься, возвращая в геттере не `birthDate`, а его копию:

```
final class Person {

    Person (Date birthDate, String name) {
        this.birthDate = new Date(birthDate.getTime()); 
        this.name = name;
    }

    private Date birthDate;
    private String name;

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return new Date(birthDate.getTime());
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
Date birthDate = new Date();
Person p = new Person(birthDate, "vega");   
// сейчас birth date - текушая дата
birthDate.setTime(0);
// и сейчас тоже
Date d = p.getBirthDate();
d.setTime(0);
// и даже сейчас
```

Теперь изменить внутреннее состояние вашего класса невозможно. Если предположить, что нельзя использовать Reflections API. От Reflections защиты (почти?) нет, он позволяет менять даже `private` и `final` поля и вызывать `private` методы.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ!